I'm trying to implement a bubble sort in ampscript for sfmc but it doesn't work
%%[
set @array = "1,3,11,6,4,8,24,27,13,99,7771,26"
set @arrayList = BuildRowsetFromString(@array, ",")
set @arrayLength = RowCount(@arrayList)
for @i = 1 to Subtract(@arrayLength, 1) do
  for @j = 1 to Subtract(@arrayLength, @i) do
    set @currentElement = Field(Row(@arrayList, @j), 1)
    set @nextElement = Field(Row(@arrayList, Add(@j, 1)), 1)
    if FormatNumber(@currentElement) > FormatNumber(@nextElement) then
      /* Swap the elements */
      set @temp = @currentElement
      SetField(Row(@arrayList, @j), 1, @nextElement)
      SetField(Row(@arrayList, Add(@j, 1)), 1, @temp)
    endif
  next @j
next @i

/* Output the sorted array */
set @sortedArray = ""
for @i = 1 to RowCount(@arrayList) do
  set @element = Field(Row(@arrayList, @i), 1)
  if @i == RowCount(@arrayList) then
    set @sortedArray = Concat(@sortedArray, @element)
  else
    set @sortedArray = Concat(@sortedArray, @element, ", ")
  endif
next @i 

outputline(concat("Sorted Array: ", @sortedArray))
]%%

this is the code please help

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

There's no SetField function in AMPscript.  AI engines are terrible at AMPscript.  Can you elaborate on what you're trying to solve in your email or CloudPage?

There is no function called SetField in AMPscript. You would typically encounter an error if you tried to execute AMPscript code using that function. However, if your goal is to sort an array, I recommend using the code provided below to achieve this. Relying solely on AMPscript for this task can be tricky, especially when trying to compare values with if FormatNumber(@currentElement) > FormatNumber(@nextElement), as it may not work as expected. There are different way to achieve this in Javascript, as we are dealing with numeric, the below code will be more cleaner. Please refer to the document: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39202616/difference-between-sort-sortfunctiona-breturn-a-b-and-sortfunctiona. Therefore, you can use the following code. This code is to be used in the email template to display the sorted order (used both ampscript and SSJS) or else we should be good with SSJS (Landingpage/ microsite/ code resource)
%%[
    SET @arrayString = "1,3,11,6,4,8,24,27,13,99,7771,26";
    

]%%
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load('Core','1');

    var arrayString = Variable.GetValue("@arrayString");

    var array = arrayString.split(",");

    array.sort(function(a, b) {

        return a - b;

    });

    var sortedArrayString = array.join(",");
    
    Variable.SetValue("@shortedArray", sortedArrayString);

</script>

SortedArray: %%=v(@shortedArray)=%%


Did you use AI to generate this answer? That's be quite ironic if you did (and also not allowed on this site).

I also have to wonder if using SSJS is appropriate here. A brief search of documentation also seems to recommend against mixing AMPscript and SSJS.

@DerekF, I refer the below Javascript code to achieve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39202616/difference-between-sort-sortfunctiona-breturn-a-b-and-sortfunctiona. There are different ways to achieve this. I prefer to use this as it is more cleaner and we are dealing with numeric sort. To avoid confusion I will add the same in the answer as well.
